# IE10 Compatibility View

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-8, internet-explorer-10, windows-server-2008-r2, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I am using Windows Server 2008 R2 and IE10 version but my client is using Windows8 with IE10.I developed an web applciation in asp.net with C# coding it is working fine in my system in all the settings of IE10. But in client machine, its not working in IE 10. But if i will chnage from IE10 to IE 10 Compat Mode then its working.

Steps I followed-
1. I installed Framework 4.5 
2. I added Metatag -

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />
```

but still its not working in IE10.

Comment: What exactly is "not working in IE 10"? **IE10 Compat Mode** is **IE7** mode, not IE9 mode, so you want your token to be **IE=EmulateIE7**.

Comment: I tried all type of <b>EmulateIE</b>, its wworking in Windows Server 2008 but when we are talking about Windows8 its not working. Few buttons and Few links are not working in Windows8.